# What is the CORRECT to use PHP in interacting with operating system

Tags: php, laravel

I am a somewhat experienced web developer who is interested in gaining more experience with Laravel.  For this purpose, I am hoping to write a Laravel-based control panel for my home server.  Again, this is more for the learning experience than anything else.  My question is this:  What is the correct way to go about controlling system-level services without creating a massive security hole?

I know all about exec and the like, but I'm wondering what is the generally accepted way of accomplishing this?  I've considered a couple options:

First, I considered writing a 'front-end-ish' Laravel app that the user can interact with, click buttons, etc and that issues commands through a unix socket to a 'backer-end' service (probably in Python) that reads the commands and executes those that are white-listed - thus bypassing (or reducing) the command-injection issue.  This would allow me to give php-fpm very limited rights, but would be A LOT more work.

On the flip side I've considered just sanitizing the hell out of any user input, and giving php-fpm elevated rights on the system.  Obviously this would be faster, and easier to manage, BUT would run the risk of opening a major security hole.

Ultimately I'm curious if someone with more experience could weigh in on this?  Am I missing a better approach?  What is the standard way to do this?  Or is there no standard way?  Everything is running on Ubuntu Server, with Nginx and PHP-FPM.  I've done a fair amount of reading on the subject, but have yet to find answers to the questions above.  Also, I'm am a pretty savvy Linux admin - but if I'm doing something stupidly don't be afraid to say so :)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the day we solved this by separating things out into two applications.  Rather than call tasks directly, your web application would write state down to dispatch tables.  In over simplified terms, if you needed the frontend application to call

```
cp /file/one /file/two
```

Your application would write data out to a table that looked something like this (again, over simplified)

```
command     arguments            job_type         has_run
cp          /file/one,/file/two  account_setup    0
```

Then, there'd be a separate application whose job it was to monitor this table, and run any commands that needed running.  This removed the need to give the PHP process any sort of elevated privileges.  It also gave us the ability to have the application control servers it wasn't on.  The separate application for running jobs also gave us a second chance at sanitizing strings, and a de-facto log of any attempts to attack the application. Finally, with a seperate application for running jobs we could use different user accounts to run different sort of jobs, and give those accounts only the permissions they needed.

If you wanted an ultra modern approach I imagine you'd try utilizing a message queue rather than the poor mans "queue via MySQL table and cron" -- the important bit is your PHP application shouldn't run the commands, your PHP application should send an event that a command needs to run.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the idea I was trying to articulate above - although I probably did a poor job at it.  I do like this, and although it would likely mean more work, it is far better than giving the web app elevated rights.  Can you recommend any further reading on the subject?

Comment: Laravel's queue documentation is probably a good place to start. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues  Also, looking at how systems like cPanel and its various clones handle this would be another place to start digging.

Answer (score 0):

if u dont want a giant security whole dont accept any user input. Only have specified shell scripts that execute the commands.

you can use shell_exec()  and only execute shell scripts on the server.

Comment: Yeah, that goes without saying.  Part of the issue is I am uber paranoid about giving php-fpm the elevated perms necessary to run something like service xyz start|stop|restart, etc...

Comment: @CRK as long as you either don't use user input in your commands or sanitize your user input _properly_, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Process Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) which is pre-required with Laravel. However you still need to carefully plan the implementation, user input should only used for command options/arguments.